Find the next datetime determined by overlaping intervals
I can have at maximum N intervals running in the same period. An interval starts at time X and ends at time X + 7 (one week).
Is there any way to get the next date where I can start a new interval such that I don't exceed N? For example:
N=3

1       8
|-------|
 2       9
 |-------|
  3       10
  |-------|

        8
        |--- can start here

A table example:
CREATE TABLE intervals (
    num int,
    valid_from datetime,
    valid_until datetime
);
INSERT INTO intervals 
  (num, valid_from, valid_until)
VALUES
  (1, NOW(), ADDDATE(NOW(), 7)),
  (2, ADDDATE(NOW(), 1), ADDDATE(NOW(), 8)),
  (3, ADDDATE(NOW(), 2), ADDDATE(NOW(), 9));

I tried some approaches using window functions, but I am not sure how to make them run over time intervals instead of rows. Maybe this is not the best approach, but I am wondering if this is possible to do in SQL only.

It might be possible but it will not be easy :) first your query needs to be able to identify the intervals within N and from when to start looking, that's the hard part I think, also it is not clear whether the intervals in N can have the same start date? Once you can identify the intervals in N you can get the min interval max date from it (the interval) and add 1 but that's not just it, you would also need to check if the date you just found already doesn't have N or <N intervals on it.

Tricky. Will the intervals always be monotonically increasing? Meaning, would you ever be trying to slot an interval starting before the latest existing value if it satisfies the constraints? Assume n=7. Say you have 13 records in your data, the earliest 7 of which overlap with a max date of 2024-04-01. Then the latter 6 overlap with a minimum start date of 2024-04-08. Would we say, 2024-04-02 is the next valid start, because we still have 1 slot available in that range. Or 2024-04-08 (and some time precision) because it must start after what's already existing.

Your comments encourage me to do it on the backend. And to answer your questions: we can have multiple intervals starting exactly at the same datetime if we do not exceed N. @Error_2646 2024-04-02 would be chosen. As to when to start looking, I was thinking looking at all intervals in range [now -7d, onwards) after they're sorted

UNION all dates, add weight, +1 for start and -1 for finish. Calculate cumulative SUM. Search the least finish date which is not present in starts and whose cumsum less than 3.

Can’t you just sort by end date, start with the latest record and go back N records?

@Akina that does not produce a correct output. if we have only one interval 1-8, we should get 1 since we still able to fit a couple more intervals until N (e.g., 3)

Consider case when we do not any assumption about intervals (regularity,duration and so on).

Collect all events - start and stop process (interval).
Count running intervals for every event time - qty.
Calculate max count running intervals for every row - from this row to last, ordered by event date - maxnext.
Find first (one) row, where running intervals qty<N and further running intervals all <N.

See example.
Test data



num
valid_from
valid_until




1
2024-07-19 23:58:45
2024-07-26 23:58:45


2
2024-07-20 23:58:45
2024-07-27 23:58:45


3
2024-07-21 23:58:45
2024-07-28 23:58:45


4
2024-07-22 23:58:45
2024-07-29 23:58:45



Output before filter and limit



num
dt
running
qty
maxnext




1
2024-07-19 23:58:45
1
1
4


2
2024-07-20 23:58:45
1
2
4


3
2024-07-21 23:58:45
1
3
4


4
2024-07-22 23:58:45
1
4
4


1
2024-07-26 23:58:45
-1
3
3


2
2024-07-27 23:58:45
-1
2
2


3
2024-07-28 23:58:45
-1
1
1


4
2024-07-29 23:58:45
-1
0
0



Result



num
dt
qty
maxnext




2
2024-07-27 23:58:45
2
2



with t as(
  select *
    ,max(qty)over(order by dt rows between current row and unbounded following)maxnext
  from(
    select num,dt,running,sum(running)over(order by dt)qty
    from(
      select num,valid_from dt, 1 running
      from intervals
      union all
      select num,valid_until, -1 running
      from intervals
    )allevents
  )running_qty
)
select  *
from t
where qty<3 and maxnext<3
order by dt 
limit 1

demo
Update1. For case when your data have gaps, as shown in comment and fiddle (dbfiddle.uk/Hvs8LdKG):
When we want find time slots, available to run next service process, we can find time intervals, where running process count < N.
with allevents as(
 select num,dt,running,sum(running)over(order by dt)qty
    ,row_number()over(order by dt) rn
 from(
    select num,valid_from dt, 1 running
    from intervals
    union all
    select num,valid_until, -1 running
    from intervals
  )x
)
,t as(
  select *
    ,sum(newgr)over(order by dt)grn
  from(
    select num,dt,running,qty,rn
      ,case when qty>=3 and lag(qty,1,0)over(order by dt)<=2
              or qty<=2 and lag(qty,1,0)over(order by dt)>=3
        then 1 else 0 end newgr
    from allevents
 )running_qty
)
,grint as(
  select grn,min(rn)n1,max(rn)n2
    ,min(dt)fromdt,max(dt) todt
    ,min(qty)qtymin,max(qty) qtymax
    ,lead(min(dt))over(order by grn) nextgrdt
    ,case when adddate(min(dt),7)<lead(min(dt))over(order by grn)
          or lead(min(dt))over(order by grn) is null
        then 1 else 0 end slot
--  ,timediff(nextEvent,dt) td
  from t
  group by grn
)
-- select * from grint order by grn;

select fromdt,nextgrdt todo -- *
from grint
where slot=1 
order by grn
-- limit 1

Let's reduce task to a dumb task like "gaps and islands".  Group consecutive rows where the number of running processes is more than 3 and less than 3.



num
dt
running
qty
rn
newgr
grn




1
2024-07-23 09:21:17
1
1
1
0
0


2
2024-07-24 09:21:17
1
2
2
0
0


3
2024-07-25 09:21:17
1
3
3
1
1


4
2024-07-26 09:21:17
1
4
4
0
1


1
2024-07-30 09:21:17
-1
3
5
0
1


2
2024-07-31 09:21:17
-1
2
6
1
2


3
2024-08-01 09:21:17
-1
1
7
0
2


4
2024-08-02 09:21:17
-1
0
8
0
2


5
2024-08-12 09:21:17
1
3
9
1
3


6
2024-08-12 09:21:17
1
3
10
0
3


7
2024-08-12 09:21:17
1
3
11
0
3


5
2024-08-19 09:21:17
-1
0
12
1
4


6
2024-08-19 09:21:17
-1
0
13
0
4


7
2024-08-19 09:21:17
-1
0
14
0
4



Grouped intervals



grn
n1
n2
fromdt
todt
qtymin
qtymax
nextgrdt
slot




0
1
2
2024-07-23 09:21:17
2024-07-24 09:21:17
1
2
2024-07-25 09:21:17
0


1
3
5
2024-07-25 09:21:17
2024-07-30 09:21:17
3
4
2024-07-31 09:21:17
0


2
6
8
2024-07-31 09:21:17
2024-08-02 09:21:17
0
2
2024-08-12 09:21:17
1


3
9
11
2024-08-12 09:21:17
2024-08-12 09:21:17
3
3
2024-08-19 09:21:17
0


4
12
14
2024-08-19 09:21:17
2024-08-19 09:21:17
0
0
null
1



Then, take all or one available time slots



fromdt
todt(nextgrdt)




2024-07-31 09:21:17
2024-08-12 09:21:17


2024-08-19 09:21:17
null



Demo

This approach works well when we have no gaps. But if we do have such gaps, we run into an issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/Hvs8LdKG.
For 1-8,2-9,3-10,20-27,20-27,20-27 we should return 8
